# Doing "evil" or "good" after being self-realized wont affect such an "individual" because he is not bound to the illusion of the material, yes or no?

Tags: karma, practice, moksha, maya, mukti

When self realized,you understand the illusion and rise above the illusion. It wont matter if you do good or evil since the concept of good and evil is something that is bound to the illusion and the material, hence it wont affect you when you are freed from the illusion. Good and evil are just 2 sides of same coin, yes or no?

PS!: Dont bother saying things like there is no "I" or similiar statements or explanations, since if I dont use these specific words no one would understand what I am asking. LOL! Just answer my question directly, please. Thanks

Comment: Try to maintain a single account. Don't create multiple accounts.

Comment: My friend, there is a mistake made by you. I have only one single account that I am using, its this account  as an anonymous guest.

Comment: There was a same account with same name and same profile picture, That was not a successful account. So, users might think you are that person. Please register. It is free and easy. Become an active user.

Comment: Yes, he is not doer anymore only awareness.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is **Yes.**

This is what Lord Shiva says in KulArnava Tantram's 9th chapter:

> Aswamedhayutenapi BrahmahatyAtena Cha | **PunyapApairna Lipyante
>   YeshAm Brahma Hridi StithAm ||**
>
> ...............
>
> Those who have realized self (or Brahman) are neither affected by the
>   performance of thousands of Aswamedha yajna nor by the sins of killing
>   numerous Brahmins.

In this verse, performance of Aswamedha is taken as an example of an act of high merit (punya) and killing Brahmins is taken as an example of an act of great demerit (papa).

One, who has attained self, is unaffected by both. This is the purport of the verse.

> Tattvanishtashya Cha KarmAni PunyApunyAni Samkshyam | **PrayAnti Naiva
>   Lipyante KriyamAnAni VA Punaha ||**
>
> .......
>
> The person who has attained tattva gyana (or the knowledge of self)
>   has  all his karmas (both good and bad) destroyed. **And he
>   is not affected even if he performs those karmas again.**
>
> **KulArnava Tantram 9-128.**

The Shiva Samhita also says the same thing:

> [image]
>
> ......
>
> He who contemplates on this [the lotus at the Ajna Chakra or on the
>   Itara Shiva linga that is situated there], standing or walking,
>   sleeping or waking, **is not touched by sins, even it were possible
>   for him to do the sinful works.**

Answer (score 1):

Asking whether Self realized being does good or evil is like asking whether a stone perceives past or present. Self realized being is **no more doer, he is awareness only.** He has transcended the doership. From Ashtāvakra Geeta.

> Surely one who knows 
>   **That is not touched by virtue or vice**, 
>   just as space is not touched by smoke, though it seems to be. 4.3

Also from the same,

> Doing and not-doing 
>   both arise from ignorance. 
>    I know this. 
>    And I am here. 
>  12.6

So your question - `Doing evil or good after being self realized has affects or not?` 
is a flawed & self contradictory question, simply because

> How can he be self realized until he is doer?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want you to note, that what I was searching for was not really an answer to a question I did not know, as the answer is already with me. Rather I was looking for people with both agreeing, and if there exists, people with disagreeing opinions - to see what they have to say and share.

Comment: Who is the guy on the picture?

Comment: @Preferanonymous Siddharameshwar Maharaja